Channel State Information Tool for Linux
I want a tool to obtain and analyze the Channel State Information of the Wi-Fi signals in my Linux pc. Example
So far, I've searched for many tools and all of them require either Intel or Qualcomm Wi-Fi chips.
I have a TPLink Wi-Fi adapter with me. Is there any opensource tool that'll let you obtain CSI using a TPLink adapter
TIA

TP-Link doesn't make Wi-Fi chips. What hardware do you have inside the TP-Link adapter? (I suspect a Realtek of some sort.)

Sorry, product recommendations and host configurations/issues are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic]. You might want to try on [unix.se].
